# Sticky section scrolling javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not found a solution to do what I want to do yet, but I am sure there is.

I have a scrollable div (overflow), with divs inside of it. The scrolling use is intended for touchscreens.

I want the user to be able to scroll as he likes, but as soon as he stops scrolling, the first div that's entirely within the viewport of the parent div needs to stick to the top of the parent div.

Basically like a casino roulette I guess. You can't have a div partially visible, halfway out of the viewport, if you stopped scrolling. You can only have that when scrolling.

Another example is [time selector like the iphone one](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/datetime.png)

If you stop scrolling, the closest value gets selected. That's what I need, within a parent div.

This is my html structure, the inside div is only to get rid of the scrolling bar:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pos = $('.current').offset();
    var left = (pos.left - $('#inside_left').offset().left);
    var right = (pos.top - $('#inside_left').offset().top);
    $("#inside_left").scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert('bottom');
        }
    });
    $('#inside_left').click(function () {
        $('#frame_current').css("height", $('.current').height());
        $('#frame_current').css("width", $('.current').width());
        if ($('.current').isOnScreen() == true) {
            alert('icansee');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#left_column {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inside_left {
    width: 125%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="inside">
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <div class="section"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to provide your current script, and css if you want people to help you.

Comment: Edited with what i have. I have been looking into plugins like scrollify but these don't work, what they do is you just have to swipe once to get to the next slide. I'm trying to have a normal scrolling while the finger is touching the screen, and then re-adjust the list when the finger stops touching the screen.

Comment: Ok 1. Your [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not **Complete** or **Verifiable** in it's current state. We should be able to see the problem without adding filler code to see the problem, and 2. You should simplify your question, images showing what you want say more than words, and clarify what you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use full page sections, which seems to me the only solution if you want to stick each section when the user stops scrolling, then you can do it using my fullPage.js library.

Just use the option `normalScroll:true` like [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html).

The option `fitToSection` to cause the "sticky effect" is activated by default.